# Saber de onde vem o clique quando se tem multiplas opções

Tags: javascript, jquery

Neste caso:

```
$('body').on('click', '.a, .b, .c', function(e) {
...
```

como saberei quando o clique veio de .a ou de .c por exemplo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dentro desse event handler podes usar o `this`. O `this` é o elemento delegado. Para sabers se um dado elemento tem uma classe podes usar o `el.classList`.

Dá uma olhada aqui (http://jsfiddle.net/sze95py7/), este exemplo:

```
$('body').on('click', '.a, .b, .c', function (e) {
    console.log(this, this.classList);
});
```

Assim para saber se é o elemento com a classe `a` podes fazer

```
if(this.classList.contains('a')){
    // fazer algo
}
```